# Independent sets and cycles in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Question : Consider a connected graph $G$ containing $n$ nodes, where $n\geq 5$. Show that there always exists at least one of :

1) Independent set containing $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$ nodes.

2) A simple cycle of length at least $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$.

An independent set is defined as a set of nodes, such that there exists no edges between any 2 elements in the set.

My first guess was a proof by contradiction. I assumed there is no cycle of length $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$ and tried to prove there must exist a independent set, and vice versa. However, both approaches yielded no results. I'm unsure what information can be deduced from one of the conditions being false to apply and show the other condition must be true.

Comment: Can you give some context to the problem? For example where did you read it? This may be a special case of some result related to cycle complete Ramsey numbers.

Comment: @Shahab This was a question in a test on algorithms. This was the last question in the set so it was one of the harder questions.

Comment: If you drop the condition of connectivity then basically the problem is of showing that $n$ is an upper bound for the Ramsey number $R(K_{\lceil\sqrt n\rceil},C_{\lceil\sqrt n\rceil})$. Theorem 5 in [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S009589567380005X?via%3Dihub) paper may be relevant.

Comment: @Shahab Not exactly. If $n$ were an upper bound for that Ramsey number, then a graph of order $n$ would have to contain an independent set of $\lceil n\rceil$ vertices or else a cycle of length **exactly** $\lceil n\rceil$, but the question only asks for an independent set of $\lceil n\rceil$ vertices or a cycle of length **at least** $\lceil n\rceil$. For $n=5$ the stronger statement is false but the weaker one is true.

Comment: @bof I meant trying to prove it vice versa as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the fact that every graph with $\chi(G) \geq 3$ has a cycle of length at least $\chi(G)$ (see Corollary 3 in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1381213)).

To solve the problem at hand, assume that $\alpha(G) < \sqrt{n}$. Then $\chi(G) \geq \frac{n}{\alpha(G)} > \sqrt{n} > 2$, so one has $\chi(G) \geq 3$, and it follows that $G$ has a cycle of length at least $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: (I'm not sure if this is the easiest way, but I don't know any other proof.)

Comment: @bof Indeed, it seems that my proof does not use connectedness. But one can also see directly that this is not needed. Suppose that $G_1,\ldots,G_k$ are the components of $G$. Let $G'$ denote the graph obtained from $G$ by adding one edge between $G_i$ and $G_{i+1}$ for every $i$. This does not introduce new cycles, and only decreases the independence number. Thus, if the conclusion is true for all connected graphs (in particular, for $G'$), then it is also true for $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I've solved it now. My solution was that you can find an independent set by greedily choosing the vertices with the least degree. The only time this will not yield a result is when at some point the minimum degree is $\lceil \sqrt{n}\rceil - 1$, because otherwise we will have enough nodes to choose from, since the decrease in nodes is the degree of the graph. If that is the minimum degree in the new graph, we can say there exists a cycle of degree of $\lceil \sqrt{n}\rceil$  in this graph. It was a test on algorithms, so I think this was the intended solution.

Comment: @adityajain I think others might be interested in your solution, so it might make sense to post it as a solution in order to make it more visible ;-)

Comment: @adityajain very nice! I second user2316602's motion — it would be nice to have this as a separate answer.